# PMF of number of heads of 4 coin tosses

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

**Let X equal the number of heads in four independent flips of a coin. Using
certain assumptions, determine the pmf of X and compute the probability that X
is equal to an odd number.**

I initially thought that x could equal {0,1,2,3,4}. And I also initially thought that the probability of getting 0 heads is just as likely as getting 4 heads given that we use a normal fair coin. I don't know if this is right though. Also I'm very lost on how to compute the probability that X is an odd number (getting 1 or 3 heads out of 4 flips).

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: With just $4$ tosses, why not just _list_ the $16$ possible outcomes that you might observe, and _count_?

Comment: @DilipSarwate because I need a mathematical way to solve it in case i have a problem with 1000000000 possible outcomes.

Comment: I think this must be the Pmf $p(x) =\dfrac{4\choose x}{16}$ for $x = 0,1,2,3,4$, and $0$ elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the probability of 0 heads is equal to the probability of 4 heads -- there is one way to get each, and each coin flip has equal probability so the probability for each case is

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{16}$$

The probability of getting 1, 2, or 3 heads is different. For example, there are four ways to get 1 heads:

HTTT

THTT

TTHT

TTTH

Each of these cases has probability $1/16$ as before, but there are 4 of them so the total probability of getting 1 heads is $4/16$.

It is a similar procedure to count the number of ways to get 2 or 3 heads. More generally, the number of ways to get $x$ heads out of $n$ coin tosses is given by the binomial coefficient:

$$n \choose x$$

To generalize even further, this coin tossing experiment follows the binomial distribution. If the probability of tossing a heads is $p$ then the PMF is given by

$$P(X = x) = {n \choose x} p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$$

In this case, for a fair coin $p = 1/2$ so the distribution simplifies a bit.

Comment: The ways to get a head do not matter. For example, getting one head out of four flips (x=1), HTTT is the same as TTTH. As long as there is one head somewhere in the four flips for x=1, order does NOT matter.

Comment: HTTT and TTTH map to the same event $X = 1$ so you have to add their probabilities (and the other two cases) to get the total probability that you get exactly one heads. I believe this is how you mean to define $X$.

Comment: @ColeHowie Exactly. If an event happens when any of several *mutually exclusive* outcomes occur, the probability of the event is the *sum* of the probabilities of the individual outcomes.  So it is *because* order does not matter that we must consider the ways the outcomes of the event could be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
And I also initially thought that the probability of getting 0 heads is just as likely as getting 4 heads given that we use a normal fair coin
```

This is correct.

The combination for 1 head and 3 tails is $h,t,t,t$ and gives $\frac{4!}{3!\cdot 1!}$ permutations.

Thus the probability for 1 head and 3 tails is $P(X=1)=\frac{4!}{3!\cdot 1!} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{4!}{3!\cdot 1!} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) ^4$

This probability is equal to $P(X=3)$.

The calculations for the other probabilities are similarly.

Comment: Thanks!! How could I set up a pmf for this though to solve for X being only odd. I know how to do it in a permutation binomial set-up, but not in a pmf way.

Comment: You can create a table: First row x | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 And the second row P(X=x) | $(1/2)^4$ | | ... The cells in the second row has to be filled with the corresponding probabilities.